# Handling Checkboxes through custom actions in windows installer and visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project

I have developed a setup project in Visual studio 2008. In my setup project I have UI dialog having 5 checkboxes. According to user's selection of checkboxes, I want to pass few arguments to another .exe which will run after the installation is complete. I am trying to do this using custom actions. I know how to pass an argument to an .exe if only one check box is checked. But if more than one checkboxes are selected then, I am not able to figure out how to pass an argument. For example, if user selects checkbox1 and checkbox2 then i want to pas '-a' and '-b' as arguments to another .exe. If user selects checkboxes 2,3 and 5 then I want to pass arguments as '-b','-c' and '-e'. Please guide me on the same. How to modify condition field to do this? (The problem is I want to run the same .exe with different arguments depending upon the checkbox selection. I knw how to run different .exe for different checkboxes :-/ ). 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your requirements are simply not supported by visual studio deployment projects.